# iOS-Developer login issues - iTunes connect has dual account sign in - restricting app upload

Tags: app-store-connect

I do not think this question is off-topic. It pertains to programming and there is no better category for it.

After configuring an app ID through a client's developer account, i compiled the app and added their identity to my xcode. Now whenever I login to their itunes connect, I see my apps and I have no way to use their account.

How do I unlink these two accounts?

My client's account is a business account.

[image]

Comment: You log in with your Client's account and your apps show up?

Comment: How can that be? So does his account show up with his and your apps or does simply your account open?

Comment: my account is open with the client's name on the top of mine as the one who is logged in in blue, with my name in gray underneath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up contacting apple and they resolved the problem. Turned out to be an internal database problem.